# How to update or replace dependencies from other library in Maven probject?

Tags: maven

My project is using another library commons-collection, which I have no control of. I run the command:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=commons-collections

Verbose not supported since maven-dependency-plugin 3.0
[INFO] com.jde.jnlu:jnlu-qe-web:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- com.jde.jimi3.data:jd-jimi3-data-sdk:jar:3.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    \- com.jde.jmq:jmq-client-spring:jar:2.1.2:compile
[INFO]       \- com.jde.jmq:jmq-client-core:jar:2.1.2:compile
[INFO]          \- com.jde.jmq:jmq-client-json:jar:1.2.9:compile
[INFO]             \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO]                \- commons-collections:commons- 
             collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
```

As it can been seen, the "commons-collections" is introduced by jd-jimi3-data-sdk which I can't update. But I was reminded of the current version of "commons-collection" has a potential security issue and needs to be upgraded. How can I achieve that in my project?

Answer (score -1):

In your project, if you declare an explicit dependency on the version of commons-collection that you want, Maven will use that instead. See Maven documentation: [Resolving conflicts using the dependency tree](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html).

If you want to be really sure, you can also (in addition to the above) exclude commons-collection from your jd-jimi3-data-sdk dependency. Something like:

```
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.jde.jimi3.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>jd-jimi3-data-sdk</artifactId>
      <version>3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions> 
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

This is also covered in the Maven documentation: [Dependency Exclusions](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html#Dependency_Exclusions).

**Warning**: Since the library you are using - jd-jimi3-data-sdk - was not written with this version of commons-collections, and allegedly not tested with it, this may break you project!